# Multiple Batch Command using WFA

Tags: c#, batch-file, command-line

I have a program to write some commands to batch file. When i debug this, the program writes nothing and just changes the line.

There are multiple commands which are separate, so i use `if(ex* = true)` to designate command sequence. once, i changed standard input to `console.writeline` it does nothing.

When i debug with standardinfo, batch file loop continuously, which is happen when nothing or wrong input are made. but `console.writeline` just stop at the moment where first command should be input.

I think maybe problem is that I don't give a time to write? but when I write code `pro.waitforexit()` the program just freezes. so I'm not sure what is wrong.

**Code**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs f) 
{
    pro.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(textBox1.Text, "reproject_v1.2.bat");
    pro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    pro.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    pro.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => myMethod(e);
    pro.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    pro.Start();
    pro.BeginOutputReadLine();

    if (ex1 == false) 
    {
        pro.StandardInput.WriteLine(textBox1.Text + @"\\");
        ex1 = true;
    }
    if (ex1 == true) 
    {
        pro.StandardInput.WriteLine("inputdata.txt");
        ex1 = false;
        ex2 = true;
    }
    if (ex2 == true) 
    {
        pro.StandardInput.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
        ex2 = false;
        ex3 = true;
    }
    if (ex3 == true) 
    {
        pro.StandardInput.WriteLine("y");
        ex3 = false;
        ex4 = true;
    }
    pro.StandardInput.Close();
    pro.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Check output files are exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the internals but `WriteLine()` seems not to block until the batch receives the standard input. `Flush()` neither. But asynchronous version `WriteLineAsync()` and `FlushAsync()` complete after the batch receives the input. I think this is what you need to send multiple standard inputs to a batch.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pro = new Process();

    pro.StartInfo.FileName = @"my.bat";
    pro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    pro.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

    pro.Start();
    pro.BeginOutputReadLine();

    // fails
    //pro.StandardInput.WriteLine("my input 1");
    //pro.StandardInput.WriteLine("my input 2");
    //pro.StandardInput.WriteLine("my input 3");

    // fails
    //pro.StandardInput.WriteLine("my input 1");
    //pro.StandardInput.Flush();
    //pro.StandardInput.WriteLine("my input 2");
    //pro.StandardInput.Flush();
    //pro.StandardInput.WriteLine("my input 3");
    //pro.StandardInput.Flush();

    // OK
    pro.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync("my input 1").Wait();
    pro.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync("my input 2").Wait();
    pro.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync("my input 3").Wait();

    // also OK
    //pro.StandardInput.WriteLine("my input 1");
    //pro.StandardInput.FlushAsync().Wait();
    //pro.StandardInput.WriteLine("my input 2");
    //pro.StandardInput.FlushAsync().Wait();
    //pro.StandardInput.WriteLine("my input 3");
    //pro.StandardInput.FlushAsync().Wait();

    pro.StandardInput.Close();
    pro.WaitForExit();
}
```

my.bat

```
set /p input1="input1: "
echo %input1%
ping localhost > nul

set /p input2="input2: "
echo %input2%
ping localhost > nul

set /p input3="input3: "
echo %input3%
ping localhost > nul
```

`ping` is for sleep.